# tyepof being added to generic argument

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a factory that uses a generic type and is passed a class for instantiation but am having trouble with typescript changing the generic type behind the scenes. Here is a minimal reproduction of the issue:

```
export interface Repository<T> {
  add(data: T): Promise<void>;
}

export const createRepository =
  <T>(schema: T) =>
  (): Repository<T> => ({
    async add(data) {
      // some business logic
    },
  });

// --------
// example schema, could be any "class"
class SomeSchema {
   public hello: string;

   constructor(hello: string) {
      this.hello = hello;
   }

   sayHello() {
      console.log('hello', this.hello);
   }
}

const createSomeSchemaRepo = createRepository(SomeSchema);

const someRepo: Repository<SomeSchema> = createSomeSchemaRepo();
```

How can I get the type to work here as expected without typescript adding "typeof" to the generic type I passed in?

I'm expecting `createRepository(SomeSchema)` to return a factory that returns `Repository<SomeSchema>` instead of `Repository<typeof SomeSchema>`.

The error I receive is:

> TS2322: Type  Repository<typeof SomeSchema>  is not assignable to type
>  Repository<SomeSchema>  Type  typeof SomeSchema  is missing the
> following properties from type  SomeSchema :  hello, sayHello

Comment: What's a `DataBase` here? Why is `createRepository()` returning a function that returns a `Repository` but then you annotate it with `Repository` directly? That's like saying `const x: string = () => "abc"`.  I imagine there's some underlying question here that's legitimate and will involve a construct signature like `new () => T` or something like `{prototype: T}`, but right now there isn't enough clarity. The code isn't a [mre]. Could you please [edit] it so the code clearly exemplifies what's happening?

Comment: A database is a dependency, an orm in this case. The returned function is then a factory that produces repositories that query the passed in schema. Does the database really effect the type problem I'm having? I'll remove it.. as I don't really think it effects the issue I'm experiencing

Comment: • "Does the database really effect the type problem I'm having?" Probably not, but it stops me from being able to test because `Database` isn't something my IDE knows about. • Your new code doesn't have an error anywhere, what exactly is the problem? (Possible hint: [empty classes are weird](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely), don't use them as examples)

Comment: Indeed the empty schema hides the error, will update

Comment: And what do you *do* with `schema` inside `createRepository`? Are you going to `new` it? Or look at its `prototype`? Or nothing at all (which is what you're doing now)?  I'd be inclined to just use `{prototype: T}` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NBdKgW) but I don't know if that meets your needs if you don't do anything with `schema` in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a new type for the schema parameter to accept a constructor
   type.
2. Adjust how you use createRepository to pass the schema class when
   calling the returned function.

```
export interface Repository<T> {
  add(data: T): Promise<void>;
}

export const createRepository = <T>() => (schema: new (...args: any[]) => T): Repository<T> => ({
    async add(data: T) {
      // some business logic
    },
});

// --------
// Example schema, could be any "class"
class SomeSchema {
  public hello: string;

  constructor(hello: string) {
    this.hello = hello;
  }

  sayHello() {
    console.log('hello', this.hello);
  }
}

const someSchemaRepositoryFactory = createRepository<SomeSchema>();
const someRepo: Repository<SomeSchema> = someSchemaRepositoryFactory(SomeSchema);
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it pointed me in the right direction, I will also post my solution below in case it helps anyone.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue mentioned in the accepted answer points out the problem I was experiencing, but I also wanted my types to be inferred, which is not addressed by the accepted solution. My solution looks like this:

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: unknown[]) => T;

export interface Repository<T> {
  add(data: T): Promise<void>;
}

export const createRepository =
  <T>(schema: Constructor<T>) =>
  (): Repository<T> => ({
    async add(data) {
      // some business logic
    },
  });

// --------
// example schema, could be any "class"
class SomeSchema {
   public hello: string;

   constructor(hello: string) {
      this.hello = hello;
   }

   sayHello() {
      console.log('hello', this.hello);
   }
}

const createSomeSchemaRepo = createRepository(SomeSchema);

const someRepo: Repository<SomeSchema> = createSomeSchemaRepo();
```

This solution has the advantage that when I pass in my `Schema`, the correct instantiated type is inferred from the passed in class/constructor.